# Where can I find surfnorm.m in MATLAB 2014a or 2014b?

Tags: matlab, function

I've recently been using the surfnorm function and would like to access the code to see what it's actually doing. I assume it's stored on my PC somewhere, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type in `edit surfnorm` to open it or `which surfnorm` to display the path.

Comment: Thanks! I like the simple ones. :-)